# NEXT and PREVIOUS buttons onClick not working

Tags: javascript, php

Code below does what I want, just shows 1 image at a time. 
But when I click the NEXT or PREVIOUS button the image 
does not change. I have done searches for an answer.
Being new to this type of code I am lost.

```
<input type="button" id="prev" value="Previous" onClick="previous()">
<input type="button" id="prev" value="Next" onClick="next()">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function previous() {
        if (which <= 0) {
            which = photos.length - 1;
        } else {
           which--;
        }
    }   
    document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which];

    function next(){
        if (which > $picture.length -1){
            which = 0;
        } else {
            which = which + 1;
        }
    }   
    document.images.photoslider.src=$picture[which];
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like you never defined `which`.

Comment: `which` came from where? never defined anywhere (at least i am unable to see in your given code)

Comment: You never update `photoslider.src` to the new image src. The ones you currently have are outside the onclick callbacks as such are not going to be run when you do a click

Comment: unable to see where you defined `which` and also put the `document.images.photoslider` line inside the function for both...